# What are the physics behind the hairy ball theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, topology

What are the physics behind the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem)? It seems that this theorem is a corollary of the way that vector fields are constructed or what happens to numbers when we move from three to two dimensions.

Is there any way to approach this theorem with arguments borrowed from physics?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here - why would there be physics "behind" a purely mathematical theorem? Perhaps as a comparison, what would you say are the physics "behind" something like the Stokes' theorem/fundamental theorem of calculus?